# What protocol does the Vertex VX-2200/2100 use for programming?

Tags: electronics, equipment-operation, radio-programming

I have seen a number of programming cable schematics on the internet, but I couldn't understand very much how they worked. From what I picked from all schematics, it appears the protocol uses the `CL_DATA` pin for both RX and TX, and the `CL_SW` pin to signal stuff.

However, I couldn't really understand the protocol that the radio uses. Can someone please explain? What are both the radio and the computer interfaces sending and expecting in each pin?

Comment: Just FYI: don't use the [tag:programming] tag for "radio programming" — it's for computer software. An unfortunate naming problem, I know. I'm thinking about how to improve it.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO OK. How about splitting the tags into radio-programming and computer-programming?

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. I just posted [a meta question about this](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/294/planning-tag-improvements-radio-programming-and-interfacing) and some related lacks-of-tags, if you'd like to see more of the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly: Yaesu ./ Vertex professional have kind of UART interface (similar to RS-232, different voltage), and agree, TX&RX are connected

Comment: Software protocol is (as far I know) hidden (not known / proprietary)